# Как сменить язык на android устройстве через adb? Android 12

Tags: android, locale, adb

Включил режим fastboot (на телефоне) и ввожу эту команду для смены языка (которую я нашёл в интренете) на компьютере:

```
adb shell "setprop persist.sys.locale fr-CA; setprop ctl.restart zygote"
```

но он отвечает:

```
Failed to set property 'ctl.restart' to 'zygote'.
See dmesg for error reason.
```

Как исправить или как можно сменить язык через adb на телефоне (который в бутлупе из-за одного языка и нужно обртано поставить любой другой язык)? TWRP есть. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Один чел дал ссылку с решением: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/solved-bootloop-after-changing-device-language-to-english-one.4381023/

Comment: (спасибо ему!)⠀

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно,
я вручную отредактировал /data/property/persistent_properties в TWRP, чтобы изменить en-XA на en-US.  Этого было недостаточно, телефон загрузился, но я все еще не мог разблокировать экран (System UI или что-то еще продолжало крашится каждые несколько секунд).

Поэтому я отредактировал /data/system/users/0/settings_system.xml.
Внутри была такая строка:

```
<setting id="24885" name="system_locales" value="en-XA, pl-PL"
 package="android" defaultValue="en-XA,pl-PL"
 defaultSysSet="true" preserve_in_restore="true"/>
```

Здесь я отредактировал два «en-XA» на «en-US».  Перезагрузился.  Телефон работает.  Надеюсь, это кому-то поможет!

Источник: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/solved-bootloop-after-changing-device-language-to-english-one.4381023/